# Hande input onChange event in dynamic react js form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, event-handling, this

I have a Form component with a title input and a dynamic number of ingredient inputs (the user can add and remove them with corresponding buttons). Most of the form functions properly. However, I receive a warning that I have passed a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler for the ingredient input element(s).

In `render()` for my Form component, this part should dynamically generate inputs (EDIT: by mapping from an array of ingredients in my Form's state):

```
{this.state.ingredients.map((element, i) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={i}>
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='new ingredient'
                                value={element || ''}
                                onChange={this.handleIngredientChange.bind(this)}
                            />
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
```

I thought these inputs would connect to my `handleIngredientChange` method to update the state of the `ith` ingredient name when the user changes the input value:

```
    handleIngredientChange(i, event) {
        let ingredients = [...this.state.ingredients];
        ingredients[i] = event.target.value;
        this.setState({ingredients});
    }
```

And that this method would appropriately allow react to control each input element.

I seem to be misunderstanding `this` and/or `.bind()`, because I clearly assigned `onChange={this.handleIngredientChange.bind(this)}` to the ingredient input element in my map function. When the user types in one of these inputs, we get `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.target').

Perhaps the root of the problem is that when the user types in the input, `handleIngredientChange` is not correctly set up to get the user's desired input value, but I cannot see where the error is.

I have looked at a lot of similar questions and have tried to implement their answers to no avail. Could anyone point me in the right direction on why I have not handled the `onChange` event properly? I'd be more than happy to explain my intentions further if you need me to. Many thanks in advance.

Full code:

```
export default class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: '',
            ingredients: [],
        };
    }

    handleTitleChange(event) {
        let title = this.state.title;
        title = event.target.value;
        this.setState({title});
    }

    handleIngredientChange(i, event) {
        let ingredients = [...this.state.ingredients];
        ingredients[i] = event.target.value;
        this.setState({ingredients});
    }

    removeClick(i) {
        let ingredients = [...this.state.ingredients];
        ingredients.splice(i, 1);
        this.setState({ingredients});
    }

    addClick() {
        let ingredients = [...this.state.ingredients];
        ingredients.push('');
        this.setState({ingredients});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        console.log('submit request logged')
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='recipe title'
                    value={this.state.title || ''}
                    onChange={this.handleTitleChange.bind(this)}
                />
                {this.state.ingredients.map((element, i) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={i}>
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='new ingredient'
                                value={element || ''}
                                onChange={this.handleIngredientChange.bind(this)}
                            />
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
                <input
                    type='button'
                    value='add'
                    onClick={this.addClick.bind(this)}
                />
                <input
                    type='Submit'
                    value='save'
                    onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
                />
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this helps

try change

```html
<input
                type="text"
                placeholder="new ingredient"
                value={element || ""}
                id={i}
                onChange={this.handleIngredientChange.bind(this)}
              />
```

and then alter

```js
 handleIngredientChange(event) {
    let ingredients = [...this.state.ingredients];
    ingredients[event.target.id] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ ingredients });
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-yf7rpm